# How to get telescopic sum of complicated terms?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> How the telescopic sum $$1+\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \dfrac{(2 n+1)!}{2^{2 n-1} n! (n+2)!}$$ has value $4$?

I think this has something to do with Taylor series but I'm not able to get it. Actually, while looking up for [Finding the $nth$ term of a sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410655/finding-the-nth-term-of-a-sequence) answer by Raffaele last step, there I've my confusion.

Comment: Instead of casting the series to a telescoping sum, an easier way (at least for most human) is convert it the series to an integral. Notice $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}t^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4t}}$, the sum at hand can be evaluated as:

$$1 + \sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2 n+1)!}{2^{2 n-1} n! (n+2)!}
= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n+2)!}{4^n(n+1)!^2(n+2)}
= 1 + 4\sum_{n=2}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{4^n(n+1)}\\
= 1 + 4\int_0^1 \sum_{n=2}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)^n dt
= 1 + 4\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}} - 1 - \frac{t}{2}\right)dt
= 4
$$

Comment: How it changed to integral form? Please explain it further?

Comment: You just substitute the integral representation: $\frac{1}{n+1} = \int_0^1 t^n dt$ into the sum, switching order of sum and integration to get an integral.

Comment: And how do you go about that 2nd last step of yours where you've telescoped it?

Comment: the point of this approach is it doesn't do any telescoping at all. For a way do use telescoping, see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 3):

**Method I** - as a telescoping sum

First, we rewrite the sum at hand in terms of [gamma functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
$$\mathcal{S} \stackrel{def}{=}1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n+1)!}{2^{2n-1}n!(n+2)!}
= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(2(n+1))}{2^{2n-1}\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+3)}
$$
Using the duplication formula of gamma function, we find

$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma\left(z+\frac12\right) = 2^{1-2z}\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(2z)
\quad\implies\quad
\Gamma(2(n+1)) = \frac{2^{2n+1}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma\left(n+\frac32\right)$$
This leads to
$$\mathcal{S} = 1 + \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma\left(n+\frac32\right)}{\Gamma(n+3)}$$

Notice for any $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\beta \ne \alpha+1$, we have

$$\begin{align}\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n+\beta)}
&= \frac{(n+\beta - 1) - (n+\alpha)}{\beta - (\alpha+1)}\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n+\beta)}\\
&= \frac{1}{\beta - (\alpha+1)}\left[\frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n+\beta-1)} - \frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(n+\beta)}\right]
\end{align}\tag{*1}$$
The RHS has the right form for a telescoping sum. This means for any $m > 0$, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n+\beta)}
= \frac{1}{\beta - (\alpha+1)}\left[\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\Gamma(\beta)} - \frac{\Gamma(m+\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(m+\beta)}\right]$$

For any $\gamma \in \mathbb{C}$, it is known that
$\displaystyle\;\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\Gamma(n+\gamma)}{\Gamma(n)n^\gamma} = 1$.

As a corollary, when $\beta > \alpha + 1$, 
$\displaystyle\;\lim_{m\to\infty}\frac{\Gamma(m+\alpha+1)}{\Gamma(m+\beta)} = 0$.
For such $\alpha, \beta$, we have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(n+\alpha)}{\Gamma(n+\beta)} = \frac{1}{\beta - (\alpha+1)}\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\Gamma(\beta)}$$

In particular, if we take $(\alpha,\beta) = (\frac32,3)$, we get
$$\mathcal{S} = 1 + \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\times\frac{1}{3-(\frac32+1)}\times\frac{\Gamma(\frac52)}{\Gamma(3)} = 1 + \frac{4}{\sqrt{\pi}}\times 2 \times \frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\sqrt{\pi}}{2!} = 1 + 3 = 4$$

**Method II** - as an integral.

IMHO, instead of casting $\mathcal{S}$ to a telescoping sum, an easier way (for most human) is convert $\mathcal{S}$ to an integral. 
Recall following formula for the OGF of centeral binomial coefficients.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}t^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4t}}\tag{*2}$$

We can evaluate the sum at hand as

$$\begin{align}\mathcal{S} 
&= 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(2n+2)!}{4^n(n+1)!^2(n+2)} = 1 + 4\sum_{n=2}^\infty \binom{2n}{n} \frac{1}{4^n(n+1)}\\
&= 1 + 4\sum_{n=2}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}\int_0^1\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)^n dt
= 1 + 4\int_0^1 \sum_{n=2}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)^n dt\\
&= 1 + 4\int_0^1 \left(
\color{red}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2n}{n}\left(\frac{t}{4}\right)^n}
 - 1 - \frac{t}{2}\right)dt\\
&= 1 + 4\int_0^1\left(\color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t}}} - 1 - \frac{t}{2}\right)dt = 4\end{align}$$

---

**TL;DR**

Finally, I will like to make some comments on Method I. As one can see from above derivation, if one knows the relation $(*1)$, turning the sum to a telescoping one is relatively straight forward. The real problem is for human, it is not that easy to detect the pattern embedded in $(*1)$.

For many sums involving binomial coefficients, factorials and in general any hypergeometric series, there is something 
called [Wilf-Zeilberger pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair) which may be used to find an equivalent and much simpler sum.
In most cases, finding WZ pairs by hand is impractical. However, there are algorithms which allow machine to find one (if it exists) for us!

Some CAS has implemented those algorithms and that's why they can simplify those nasty looking finite sums into a much simpler one. 
If you want to turn similar looking sums into a telescoping one, I'll recommend you first look at your CAS and see whether it has this sort of algorithms implemented!

Comment: Actually, I was asking about 2nd last step in method 2 where you removed the summation. How did you do that? Just that.

Comment: Can you provide some source where there is extensive detail on gamma function and telescoping sum?

Comment: @Mann46 For gamma function,  the wiki entry I linked in answer already has most of the properties one ever need to know. Another good online source is [DLMF Chapter 5](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5). For telescoping sum, there is not much stuff for general series (as it is usually too trivial). For sums involving binomial coefficients, factorials, try the refs in the wiki entry WZ pair. IMHO, those are way too complicated for human.

Comment: Right on point.One more thing I want to ask is how do you recognize which function's series expansion it is? Because most of the time, we don't have its chart or table. Is there any typical method here? wrt red one

Comment: @Manny46 There are not too many series one should remember. I remember $(*2)$ because it is one of the most important special case for $\frac{1}{(1-z)^\alpha} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\alpha)_k}{k!} z^k$ where $(\alpha)_k = \alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha+k-1)$ and its coefficients $\binom{2n}{n}$ appears in a particular pleasant form.